# ecplode and search in rows

Tags: php, mysql, explode

hello to all I have the id separated by a comma in a column of a table and I would like that if one of these id is equal to the id of another table otherwise showed no

tab a

```
id name surname prodoct
 1   a     a    1,6,9,more
```

tab b

```
id name surname id_product
1   a    a          1
2   b    b          1
3   c    c          2
4   e    e          9
```

result
I have to do to explode the prodct of tab a and if id_product of tab b it's the same in one of the 'explode numbers

```
    id name surname id_product
     1   a    a          1
     2   b    b          1
     4   e    e          9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by `FIND_IN_SET` and `sub-query`.

```
select * from tab_b
where FIND_IN_SET(id_product, (select prodoct from tab_a where tab_a.id = 1))
```

Comment: sorry I misspoke i need I have to do to explode the prodct of tab a and if id_product of tab b it's the same in one of the 'explode numbers

Comment: sorry is a perfect tnks